# ContentResolver wrong MIME type

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am writing a unit test in my Android app to test a ContentProvider.  This test extends ProviderTestCase2.  I have the following code:

```
    // Tests the MIME type for the recent_searches table URI.
    String mimeType = mMockResolver.getType(SearchEntryProvider.CONTENT_URI);
    assertEquals(SearchEntryProvider.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);
```

The mock ContentResolver sees the value of SearchEntryProvider.CONTENT_URI as:
**url = {android.net.Uri$StringUri@831696969096}"content://com.eazyigz.provider.RussiaMediaSearch/searches"**

The problem is that this assertEquals fails because it expects a CONTENT_TYPE of

> vnd.android.cursor.dir

but instead receives

> vnd.android.cursor.item

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the mimeType to be **vnd.android.cursor.dir**.  Anybody have experience with this?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, the problem was in my ContentProvider's implementation of **getType** method.  I had to implement it like this to return the correct **CONTENT_TYPE**:

```
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        // If the pattern is for searches, returns the general content type.
        case SEARCHES:
            return CONTENT_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_ID:
            return CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(INVALID_URI + uri);
    }
}
```